# Accept or reject cookies with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, cookies

I am trying to login to my Garmin connect account. I can enter the website by cannot get rid of the window to accept or reject cookies. Would you have a solution for this ? Here is my code:
Thanks a lot!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies": 1})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)
driver.get("https://connect.garmin.com/signin/") #loading page
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20) #defining webdriver wait

#defining username and password
username = 'xxxxx'
password = 'xxxxx\n' #\n will act as enter key

def login():
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@id='gauth-widget-frame-gauth-widget']")))
    frameLogin = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[@id='gauth-widget-frame-gauth-widget']")
    driver.switch_to.frame(frameLogin)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'username'))).send_keys(username) #userame/email
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'password'))).send_keys(password) #password

    #try to click on reject cookies
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@class='truste_popframe']")))
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@class='gwt-Frame']")))
    frameCookies = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@class='gwt-Frame']")
    driver.switch_to.frame(frameCookies)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='acceptAllButtonLower']"))).click()
    
login()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to close the popup window, get the xpath of the close button and if it's regular and appears always at loading of page you can close it.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, there is no close button in the frame...

Comment: Or completely delete the frame, sometimes gives weird results when you delete something from DOM but it may help you